# Solidity not updating value from delegate contract [SOLVED]

Tags: solidity, remix

Assuming this contract:

```
contract getSome {

    finalizeToken token;


    constructor() {
        token = finalizeToken(0xdc0974e65e479fa587118eb7588f426229a39d31);
    }

    function testWrite() public returns (bool) {
        setval();
    }

    function setval()  {
        token.setEpoch(8000);
    }

}

interface fToken {
    function setEpoch(uint _blocks) external ;
}

contract finalizeToken is fToken {
    uint public epochCount;


    constructor() {}

    function setEpoch(uint _blocks) public {
        epochCount = _blocks;
    }


}
```

For whatever reason the value of `epochCount` on the `finalizeToken` is not being updated when called trough the `getSome` contract.

I've never encountered this before, so i'd appreciate some inputs

**EDIT:** Issue found, i was using ganache instead of ropsten and it need explicit `sendTransaction` for making a call. I was using Remix with Ganache as Web3 provider, causing this behaviour.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This works, the only issue that you could be having is that you should be careful with the address in the constructor of `getSome`, deploy first `finalizeToken` and then update the address in the constructor of `getSome`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please explain in more detail your found solution about Ganache and Remix. It does not make sense to me, so I suspect something I can learn here...Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am not sure what does not makes sense to you. As I said, this smart contract should work and the OP wrote that he found the issue and was not in the smart contract but in how he was using ganache.

Comment: Yes, and I’m curious about the difference found in using ganache. I’d like to have more details about that’s What did not match for you? (BTW: do not downvote if you do not understand... )

Comment: Rick, why will I downvote you?. what do you mean when you said: "what did not match for you?" My answer says that it should work, as I tested it on Remix and it worked. I have not said that there is something that does not match. Please see the question, the OP marked as solved and he is indicating what was wrong in ganache. I personally have no interest in ganache so I cant help, I was interested in the code.